# What happens to dereferenced string literal?

Tags: java, string

```
String a="ABC";
a="BCD";
System.out.println(a); //BCD
```

What happens to "ABC"? Can someone explain me what will happen?

Comment: It will print 'BCD'

Comment: Please learn the **basics of Java** before asking.

Comment: Simply, It is value will changed and will be BCD, Because you assign this value to it. And It will print BCD

Comment: yes even I answered same but what happens to "ABC",,does it remain in constant pool or what.. I am not sure .. Please explain

Comment: Gets garbage collected

Comment: Nothing happens unless it can be observed.

Answer (score 3):

When you perform `String a="ABC"`, your string literal get's automatically added to String pool. It's kept in string pool so that JVM can reuse it if it can be.

After this, the rules for garbage collecting of string is same as that of any other object. Before we assign any other object to `a` variable, if `"ABC"` was referenced by any other variable, then it will stay there in the pool.

Otherwise, if it's not referenced anymore, then it will get garbage collected the very next time GC runs.

Answer (score 0):

'ABC' gets garbage collected since it has lost reference